# How to make video stick on top?

Tags: android, video, sticky, android-video-player, video-player

When you play video in YouTube app, at first it's full screen. When you click back button it goes to this mode:

[image: img]

I have seen similar thing made in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rtspplr.app) app.
How is it made? Is there any particularly library? Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this library https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Comment: @tyczj make this answer, so I can accept it.